# wp_insert_post() Add and specific ID to the body of that

Tags: posts, shortcode, wp-insert-post

Is there a way to add an specific ID to the body of that post that it's created by that method?

The thing is, I'm creating a new post using this

```
 $new_page = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_title' => $new_page_title,
                'post_content' => $new_page_content,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'import_id' => 999999,
            );
wp_insert_post($new_page);
```

I do that to give special styles only in that page that it's generated when the plugin is activated. As i gave the id `999999` the counter when I create a posts starts from there, 100000,100001 and so on... which i thing it's not good, so, is there a way to give the body an ID and not only adding it in the class?

Comment: What's the problem that giving a  post ID `999999` solves? Post IDs always increment, the database doesn't go back and fill in the gaps. Making it do that will mean major performance hits on saving and updating posts. Fundamentally you shouldn't need to hardcode post IDs in code, it's the magic number bad coding habit, use post slugs/names if you really have to

Comment: @TomJNowell exactly I dont want to give that ID, to the post, intead of it I want to give the ID to the body, is there any way?

Comment: What do you mean by adding an ID to the body?

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves when the page is generated, the body structure is something like this `<body class="page-id-6" id="?????"></body>` is there a way to add an ID in there??

Comment: Yes, you should edit the template file you want to change. It should be inside single.php, page.php or, maybe, header.php.

Comment: hmm can you include in your Q the code that renders the body tag? You should already have classes for both the posts tag and the body itself that you can latch on to. Also if you can provide context by describing the problem that this solves? Use the edit link underneath the tags to update your question so users don't have to read the comments